How to expand dict into f-string similar to {variable=}?
Is there a way to expand a dict into a f-string with a similar result to using the {variable=} syntax? Where each key-value pair would be treated as key=value, and items would be separated by commas?
For example:
kwargs = dict(a=5, b=2)
f'got {**kwargs=}' # results in an error:
SyntaxError: f-string: invalid syntax
# desired output: 'got a=5, b=2'


The JSON module?

print(json.dumps(kwargs, indent=4, default=str))

What's wrong with f'{kwargs=}', which outputs a perfectly readable kwargs={'a': 5, 'b': 2}?

In Python up to 3.11:
f"got {', '.join(k + '=' + str(v) for k, v in kwargs.items()) }"

Python 3.12 may allow for other, shorter ways to do that, due to the
new rules for f-strings, but I am not sure if they would be more readable.

I'd recommend using repr, not str for the value, as in most cases you'd want to see a a="abc", not a=abc. Nested f-strings can also do this, and more succinctly with the !r conversion specifier, e.g. f"got {', '.join(f'{k}={v!r}' for k, v in kwargs.items()) }". All 3.12 would add would be the ability to use the same quote characters inside the placeholder that were used on the outside (so the inner quotes could be double-quotes as well if you liked).

just go for it, pal.

Ah figured with all the dictionary expansion and formatting options this would be a thing. But good to know about the !r specifier!
